# Unable to redirect to Azure AD login

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have an existing application. Now I have configured that application to authenticate using Azure Active Directory. on button click it is redirecting to the Azure AD login to authenticate the user, after successful login it is redirecting back to the application. It is working as expected in localhost.

But When I publish the application to Azure App service it is not working. When I click on the button it is not redirecting to Azure AD.

**Code in button click**

```
public ActionResult Login()
        {
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("index", "XYZController", null);
        }
```

This is config

[image]

Redirect URLs in portal
[image]

Hope I configured everything. Still I am facing issue.
Any clue on this issue

Comment: Have you changed the configuration about redirect url in portal -> azure ad - > authentication ?

Comment: Yes @Tiny-wa, I have already added redirect urls in portal. Updated in question

Comment: Correct me I'm wrong but the issue you are facing is that when you publish your app, and click the button that should be redirecting you to the Azure AD login, this redirection to the Azure AD login is not occurring. Is this right? Were you able to solve this? I am facing a similar problem!

Answer (score 1):

In fact, your mistake is very simple. The Redirect URIs you configured in the code are inconsistent with the Redirect URIs configured in Azure portal, so you cannot redirect to Azure ad. You need to change `/Index` to `/index`, and you must give they are set to be exactly the same without capitalization.

[image]